# Determine Python regex named group numbers?

Tags: python, regex

In Python you can have a regex with named groups, such as:

```
m = re.match(r"(?P<first_name>\w+) (?P<last_name>\w+)", "Malcolm Reynolds")
```

You can look-up the matched text for the named groups by name or using `groupdict`:

```
In [202]: m.group("first_name")
Out[202]: 'Malcolm'

In [203]: m.groupdict()
Out[203]: {'first_name': 'Malcolm', 'last_name': 'Reynolds'}
```

If I want offsets for the named groups, I need to know which group number they are, so I can use something like `start(1)`.  How can I find out the mapping between the named groups and their group numbers?  If they matched the same strings, this could not be unambiguously inferred.

The purpose of this to be able to infer the named annotated spans (with offsets) in a function which has no specific knowledge of the original regex.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, so this doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The groups have offsets do they not? How do I find the offsets for a named group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you can provide the group name to `start` instead of the index.

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(?P<first_name>\w+) (?P<last_name>\w+)", "Malcolm Reynolds")
>>> m.start('last_name')
8
```

So it might not be necessary for you to map the group name to its index.

Answer (score 4):

You can get group name to index mapping if you use compiled regular expressions instead.
Like this:

```
p = re.compile(r"(?P<first_name>\w+) (?P<last_name>\w+)")
print(p.groupindex)
```

Result:

```
{'first_name': 1, 'last_name': 2}
```

---

Or you can access the pattern object from the match via the `re` attribute:

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(?P<first_name>\w+) (?P<last_name>\w+)", "Malcolm Reynolds")
>>> print(m.re.groupindex)
{'first_name': 1, 'last_name': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are trying to achieve but in case it helps, here are 2 helpful things:

1. The match object `m` has a `groups` method that will return a tuple to the matched strings. You can use integer offsets.
2. Define the tuple of group names in first place:

   `group_names = ("first_name", "last_name")`

   Then use string formatting function to create re:

   `m = re.match(r"(?P<{0}>\w+) (?P<{1}>\w+)".format(*group_names), "Malcolm Reynolds")`

   From now on, you have a unique index for the group_names.